# Ceiling fan flashes once after installation but doesn’t work

Tags: ceiling-fan

I installed a Hunter Coral Gables 2 indoor/Outdoor Fan with a remote. double checked wiring and it’s good, light flashes once. Fan or light do not come on. What could be the problem?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Please take our [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: We need a little more info here. Can't diagnose without facts on type of wall switch and pictures of the inside of the ceiling box and switch connections.